# Reconstructing a matrix from an SVD in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

Hi so basically my question is I have a matrix which I've SVD decomposed and have it in the variables u, s, and v. I've made some alterations to the s matrix to make it diagonal, as well as altered some of the numbers. Now I'm basically trying to reconstruct it into a regular matrix from the 3 matrices back into the original matrix. Does anyone know of any functions that do this? I can't seem to find any examples of this within numpy.

Comment: This is just a matrix multiplication that you can find in wikipedia, and `s` is diagonal, what do you mean you made some alterations to "make it" diagonal?

Comment: If you've ever used numpy in python 3 you might know that when you use the SVD function it will output the sigma matrix as a 1-D array of just the diagonal values. So I had to change it to be a diagonal matrix, AKA a 2-D matrix, as well as I was also doing a lower rank approximation so I made a different diagonal matrix that I will be creating a second matrix with. So I wanted to know if there was a function which reconstructed a matrix from the SVD components

Comment: So your modification was just `np.diagonal(s)`? The second part is just matrix multiplication with indexing

Answer (score 3):

The only mildly tricky bit would be "expanding" `s` If you have `scipy` installed it has [`scipy.linalg.diagsvd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.diagsvd.html#scipy.linalg.diagsvd) which can do that for you:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.linalg as la
>>> 
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> A = rng.uniform(-1,1,(4,3))
>>> u,s,v = np.linalg.svd(A)
>>> 
>>> B = u@la.diagsvd(s,*A.shape)@v
>>> 
>>> np.allclose(A,B)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just using the np.matmul() function and then just multiplying the 3 matrices of u s and v together was enough to get them back into an original matrix.