# SVD on a non-square matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, svd, decomposition

I'm using numpy.linalg.svd() to get the singular value decomposition of matrices. But I can't get back from the decomposition to the original matrix for a non-square matrix.

For example, for a square matrix :

```
import numpy as np
n=5
# make a random (n,n) matrix
A= np.reshape( np.random.random_integers(0, 9, size= n**2), (n, n))
#SVD 
U,S,Vh = np.linalg.svd(A) 
# to get A from the SVD back
A_svd = U@np.diag(S)@Vh
#check if its the same 
print(np.allclose(A,A_svd))
```

I get :  `>>> True`

Now for a non-square matrix, for example A of shape (m,n), then the shape U is (m,m), the shape V is (n,n) and S is a diagonal matrix of (of length k), with k = min(m,n). For example :

```
import numpy as np
n=5
m= 8
# make a random (m,n) matrix
A= np.reshape( np.random.random_integers(0, 9, size= m*n), (m, n))
#SVD 
U,S,Vh = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

With the following shapes :

```
>>> U.shape
(8, 8)
>>> S.shape
(5,)
>>> Vh.shape
(5, 5)
```

I dont know how to get the matrix A back if I have the svd decomposition though.
I cant do a simple multiplication because of the shapes difference.  `U@np.diag(S)@Vh`  or  `np.matmul(U,S,Vh)` or with `np.dot`.
So I tried to reshape S and fill it with zeroes.

```
S_m = np.diag(S) 
S_m.resize((U.shape[1], Vh.shape[0]))
#check if its the same 
print(np.allclose(A,U @S_m@ Vh))
```

```
>>> False
```

Comment: Restart your terminal/kernel. I use python3 and get `True`. Indeed, you need to add 0s to make the dimensions compatible for the dot product. You code works fine and returns True in both cases.

Comment: After restarting the terminal, it actually gives `True`. I don't know what was wrong before. Thank you.

Comment: you mixed/overwritten probably some variables... The original code works perfect after adding the 0s in S_m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916364/14580023), using [diagsvd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.diagsvd.html) from scipy.linalg.

```
import scipy.linalg as la    
A_svd = U@la.diagsvd(S,*A.shape)@Vh
```

Comment: Please don't link to other Stack Overflow answers. Mark as duplicate instead.